# Run Docker PHP-apache: Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: php, apache, docker

I have a folder: `my-php-app` and it contains a `Dockerfile` and a `src/` folder.
The Dockerfile is very simple:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
COPY config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
COPY src/ /var/www/html/
```

My `src/` contains an `index.php`
The `index.php` contains

```
<html>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World!</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

I did the following:

```
docker build -t my-php-app .
```

The new image was generated successfully.
Now I want to start a container from that image:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 my-php-app
```

But when I'm visiting my localhost:80 I see:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

So my question is:
How do I have to start my container properly? What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: what php.ini file have you used? Using [this one](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/php.ini-production) I've got your project working nicely

Comment: I just replaced my php.ini with yours and it's working now. If you want you can add this as answer and I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: how to add php.ini file in docker ? @Thomasleveil

Comment: in my case, only comment $ this line COPY config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/ and works fine. The first line in dockerfile put FROM php:7.2-apache

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not sharing your *php.ini* file, so I tried using the default production one [provided](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/php.ini-production) by the PHP project and using that config file, I was able to run your project fine.

I suspect your issue lies there.

Answer (score -1):

You could also just "chown -R" your files to www-data instead of your local username!